# first part of output is correct then I get a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to output the values of the vector using a function. THe values for "gv" output but when trying to output the second vector, "vv" I get segmentation fault. Can someone help me atleast understand what is going on and why I get this error. And what part of my program does this happen at as well. Thanks. Also, I am using the putty compiler that is based on a linux server

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <exception>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <limits>
    using namespace std;

    vector<int>gv{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512}; //global vector

    void f(vector<int>a) //function f that takes in a vector argument
    {
        vector<int>lv(10);

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ //loop that sets values of gv to lv
                lv[i] = gv[i];
                cout<< lv[i]<<endl;
            }

         cout<<'\n';

        vector<int>lv2 = a; //loop that assigns the values of the argument vector to lv2
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            cout<< lv2[i]<<endl;
            }

    }

    int main() {

    f(gv); //function that uses the global variable gv

    vector<int>vv(10); //creating a new vecotr vv

        for(int i = 1; i<11;++i){ //loop to assign values of the first ten factorials
            vv[0] = 1;
            vv[i] = vv[i-1]*(i+1);
        }
    f(vv); //function using vv
    }
```

Comment: Use `at` instead of `[]` and you should quickly see a problem. You should also not hardcode a size in loops, but use `.size()`, or since this is C++11, a range-based for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector`s won't automatically grow as they are indexed into, if you want to append items to the end of a vector, use `push_back`.  this will expand the vector as it needs to grow.

```
std::vector<int> vv = {1}; // initializes the vector with one element
for(int i = 1; i < 11; ++i){
    vv.push_back(vv[i-1]*(i+1));
}
```

If you want to start the vector with a specific size, you can use the constructor with argument.

```
std::vector<int> vv(10); // constructors a vector with 10 elements (all set to 0)
```

Additionally, if you want your accesses to be checked, then you can use `vv.at(i)` instead of `vv[i]`.  Using `at` will throw a `std::out_of_range` if you use an invalid index.

I could suggest using `back` instead of indexing at all, which would turn your loop into:

```
std::vector<int> vv = {1};
for(int i = 1; i<11;++i) {
    vv.push_back(vv.back() * (i+1));
}
```

The loop using `lv` and `gv` can be rewritten as a range-based loop as well
vectorlv(10);

```
for(auto&& i : gv) {
    lv.push_back(gv[i]);
    std::cout<< i << '\n';
}
```

but if that's all you need then you can just copy the vector by doing the following, and not loop at all.

```
auto lv = gv;
auto lv2 = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you create the vector you don't pass a size to the constructor so by default it is zero.

`vector<int>vv; //creating a new vecotr vv`

Then when you attempt to loop through `vv` you're accessing memory you don't own.

Also, syntactically in c/c++ usually brackets are done like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
{
   // Do stuff...
}
```

Instead of the Java way like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
   //Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: *Also, syntactically in c/c++ usually brackets are done like...* false.  That's Allman style, which is uncommon nowadays.  not unheard of, but certainly not the norm.

Comment: I get what you are saying. And so I changed the vector vv so that it would have a size of 10. But when I run it, I get the error that "glibc" detected